# access javascript ckeditor object within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, ckeditor

Lets say I have a page with an iframe and within the iframe I have a ckeditor instance that I want to destroy from the containing page.

I would usually try something like this:

```
var iframe_document = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document;
for(var i in iframe_document.CKEDITOR.instances)
  iframe_document.CKEDITOR.instances[i].destroy();
```

However it appears that the ckeditor instance can not be accessed this way.  Is it possible to destroy the instance from outside the document similar to this?

To clarify the exact error is "cannot read property 'instances' of undefined"

Comment: Is the iframe content coming from the domain of the website the script is running in?

Comment: @Eric Yes, it is a page meant to be viewed on its own outside of the iframe as well however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables belong to the window, not to the document so try this:

```
var iframe_CKEDITOR = document.getElemenyById("iframe_id").contentWindow.CKEDITOR;
for(var i in iframe_CKEDITOR.instances)
  iframe_CKEDITOR.instances[i].destroy();
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  If only you had answered earlier, i fumbled with this for hours and finally just overloaded the save button on the editor itself.  If only i had known the solution was so simple!  Looks like I have lots to learn about Javascript still.

Comment: In case of problems you should always use a proper js debugger like Firebug, that way you can see what are the objects that you have instead of doing guess work.