# Access ckeditor from casperjs test script

Tags: javascript, django, iframe, casperjs

In a django project I've loaded a ckeditor in this way

```
CKEDITOR.replace('id_content', {
     toolbar: 'Basic',
     readOnly: {{ editing|yesno:"false,true" }}
});
```

and in my casperjs script I tried to access the editor in this way

```
var ckeditor = this.evaluate(function () {
      return document.querySelector('#id_content').contentWindow.CKEDITOR; 
});

ckeditor.instances.id_content.setData( '<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>' );
```

based on what I read in this post [access-javascript-ckeditor-object-within-an-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591587/access-javascript-ckeditor-object-within-an-iframe) but console output is the following

```
FAIL TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'ckeditor.instances')
```

Any idea? Thanks!

**Edit:**

If I try to do all stuff in evaluate method the ckeditor content not changes. The following code

```
var ckeditor = this.evaluate(function () {  
    var ckeditor = document.querySelector('#id_content').contentWindow.CKEDITOR;
    ckeditor.instances.id_content.setData('<p>AAA bbb CCC </p>'); 
});

this.test.assertField('content', '<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>');
```

fails an output

```
FAIL "content" input field has the value "<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>"
#    type: assertField
#    code: this.test.assertField('content', '<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>');
#    subject: false
#    inputName: "content" 
#    actual: "<p>In et qui nobis eos. Rem impedit ullam nihil placeat in. Et ea explicabo earum quam. Earum rerum ipsum ea soluta.</p>\n"
#    expected: "<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass functions to and from page context in casperjs (and phantomjs). You can only pass primitives like Number, String, [] and {}. So `contentWindow.CKEDITOR` is probably an object created with `new`. You need to do all your stuff inside the page context and just pass the necessary strings into the page context:

```
var data = '<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>';
this.evaluate(function (contendata) {
      var ckeditor = document.querySelector('#id_content').contentWindow.CKEDITOR; 
      ckeditor.instances.id_content.setData(contendata);
}, data);
```

To make sure that ckeditor had time to make all adjustments to the page, you can `wait` a little:

```
this.thenEvaluate(function (contendata) {
      var ckeditor = document.querySelector('#id_content').contentWindow.CKEDITOR; 
      ckeditor.instances.id_content.setData(contendata);
}, data);
this.wait(1000, function(){
    this.test.assertField('content', '<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>');
}); // sec
```

or even wait for the specific data:

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
this.thenEvaluate(function (contendata) {
      var ckeditor = document.querySelector('#id_content').contentWindow.CKEDITOR; 
      ckeditor.instances.id_content.setData(contendata);
}, data);
this.waitForSelector(x("//*[contains(text(),'AAA bbb CCC')]"), function(){
    this.test.assertField('content', '<p>AAA bbb CCC</p>');
});
```

Comment: The advice is correct but the content still does not change.

Comment: @SalvatoreAvanzo I'm not familiar with `ckeditor` so I don't know it is the right call you do. Also, how do you check if it is not right? Do you make a screenshot? You might have to `wait` before doing that.